# How to extract content between braces using grep?

Tags: grep

I would like to use grep to extract only one part between braces

**My log file :***

```
     {
*         "path": "/root/power.doc"
     }
```

How to extract content between braces ?

Comment: Your log file looks like a diff on a JSON file, it might be easier to use a JSON parser such as jq to access the file directly.

Comment: indeed ! But have my action is limited.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` doesn't do ranges. You could use `awk` instead:

```
awk '/\{/,/\}/ {if($0 ~ /path/){print $0}}' kylian.log
*         "path": "/root/power.doc"
```

EDIT 1:

Here a modified file for testing:

```
$ cat kylian.log 
*         "path": "/root/power_before.doc"

    --- before
    +++ after
    @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
     {
*    -    "mode": "0010",
*    +    "mode": "0030",
*         "path": "/root/power.doc"
     }
*         "path": "/root/power_after.doc"
```

And here the output when I run my awk against it:

```
$ awk '/\{/,/\}/ {if( $0 ~ /path/){print $0}}' kylian.log
*         "path": "/root/power.doc"
```